# what does the device \device\fakevid0 stand for (windows 10)

Tags: windows-10

I found this looking around on my system using WinObj from sysinternals.com.
And I cannot open these devices -- permission denied.
What does it stand for?

There are many: \Device\FakeVid0..FakeVid15
None of them can be opened even as administrator

Answer (score 1):

This virtual device is associated with `rdpdr.sys` (“Microsoft RDP Device redirector”), a driver that is part of the Remote Desktop Protocol components. RDP supports 16 monitors by default. You’re most likely looking at the virtual video devices that are used when a remote client connects to your computer via RDP.